# How can I concat a new string inside a local variable?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can you guys please check this code, it is MVC3 Razor

```
<p><strong><u>Skills:</u></strong> @foreach (var skill in personRepo.GetAllSkillsByID(id))
                     {                                                            
                         @skill
                     }</p>
```

and here's the result for it

> Skills: CSSDesignCommutingDriving

As you can see the result doesn't have any space and comma. I just want to know how to add a comma between the results and no comma on the last result, just like this.

> Skills: CSS, Design, Commuting, Driving

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)?

```
<p>
   <strong><u>Skills:</u></strong>@(String.Join(", ", personRepo.GetAllSkillsByID(id)))
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know it. noob in .NET

Answer (score 0):

This accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
<p><strong><u>Skills:</u></strong>@(string.Join(", ", personRepo.GetAllSkillsByID(id)))</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would fix it.

```
<p><strong><u>Skills:</u></strong> @string.Join(", ", personRepo.GetAllSkillsByID(id).ToList())</p>
```